# How to compute the total variation of an image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to compute the total variation of an image in Matlab using the l1 norm of the spatial first-order derivatives. The code is below:

```
function TV = compute_total_variation1(y)
% y is the image
nbdims = 2;

% check number of channels in an image
if size(y,1)==1 || size(y,2)==1
    % we have one dimension
    nbdims = 1;
end

if size(y,1)>1 && size(y,2)>1 && size(y,3)>1
    % we have three dimensions
    nbdims = 3;
end

if nbdims==1
    TV = sum(abs(diff(y)));
    return;
end

% the total variation weight is 1
% weight_tv = ones(size(y));

g = gradient(y);
% compute using the l1 norm of the first order derivatives
TV = sum( abs(g),nbdims+1);

% TV = TV .* weight_tv;
TV = sum(TV(:));
```

Am I correctly computing the the total variation using the l1 norm?

**Edit:**

```
function TV = compute_total_variation1(y)
% y is the image
nbdims = 2;

% check number of channels in an image
if size(y,1)==1 || size(y,2)==1
    % we have one dimension
    nbdims = 1;
end

if size(y,1)>1 && size(y,2)>1 && size(y,3)>1
    % we have three dimensions
    nbdims = 3;
end

if nbdims==1
    TV = sum(abs(diff(y)));
    return;
end

% the total variation weight is 1
% weight_tv = ones(size(y));

[gx gy] = gradient(y);
% compute using the l1 norm of the first order derivatives
% horizontal
TVgx = sum( abs(gx),nbdims+1);
% vertical
TVgy = sum( abs(gy),nbdims+1);
% TV = TV .* weight_tv;
TV = sum(TVgx(:)) + sum(TVgy(:));
```

Comment: If you want to make it any faster, I would prefer something like `A = abs(img(1:end-1,:)-img(2:end,:)); B = abs(img(:,1:end-1)-img(:,2:end)); sum(A(:)) + sum(B(:))`

Answer (score 2):

You do not take into account the derivatives on the second dim:

```
g = gradient(y)
```

returns only the derivative along the horizontal dimension, in order to get the derivative along the vertical dimension as well, you need

```
[gx, gy] = gradient(y);
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the derivative along the vertical direction. Is the code valid now?